# What’s the security risk when setting the Gnome keyring password to blank on an FED system with autologin?

Tags: authentication, key-management, luks

My system disk is full encrypted with luks. My Ubuntu logs in automatically, because I am the only user. But I still need to unlock my Gnome Keyring and I wonder, if there is any sense for that. Because I always unlock the keyring when I login, so it is always accessible while the computer is running. What if I would set the password to blank, what could be the security risks?

The only reason I can imagine is, if I would do any stupid like backing up the keyfile to a non encrypted device or sending it by mail, it would still be password locked. But I shouldn't do something like that anyway.

Comment: Any malicious program you run with this user account or root privileges.

Comment: Just to add something to this, I think if you have identical login and keyring password, it's also irrelevant if they are good or not, because both (luks and keyring data) have similar attack chance.

Answer (score 1):

**There is no security risk to doing this**, assuming the following are true:

- Your disk encryption password is sufficiently strong to remain unbroken.
- The keychain will always be open any time the encrypted disk is mounted.
- You don't copy the keychain database to an unencrypted medium.
- No malicious processes attempt to access the open keychain

If you always and immediately unlock your keychain while the system is on, then there is no real benefit to encrypting it again, assuming you are using a sufficiently strong FDE password. The only real benefit to encrypting the keychain is if the database is stored on an otherwise unencrypted disk, or if you only unlock it when you need it (effectively preventing a malicious process from reading it until you enter the password, even if that malicious process has root).

Comment: This answer on Super User raises a valid attack vector when not using a password for Gnome Keyring: https://superuser.com/a/1299246

Exploits that allow the attacker to steal files, but not send D-Bus messages, can gain access to the passwords in the keyring. They would not be able to access the passwords if they were encrypted by a password for the Keyring. The author of the answer claims that there have been such exploits in the past.

To that end, I think this answer should be revised.